# Instantiating and placing characters or strings onto a board for game

Tags: c++, class

I have to create a Battleship game where the first part asks to create a Ship class and initialize five instance of the ship class:

Frigate(len 2),
Sub (len 3),
Destroyer (len 3),
Battleship (len 4),
Aircraft Carrier (len 5)

Ships have to take random spots on the board and show each ship position using the first letter of the ship name.
No hit or miss functions yet.

I feel like I have no idea how to approach this.

So far, I've created the board successful. I feel like I might have to make an area for the placements of ships on the board.

I'm so sorry. My code looks like garbage and I really need some guidance :(

Edit: I've made a ship placement function and fixed my class, but not sure if they're correct

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


const int ROWS = 10;
const int COLS = 10;
const int SHIPTYPE = 5; 

string array[ROWS][COLS];


// Create struct with horizontal and vertical coordinates
struct Arr{

int x;
int y;
};

class Ship(){

// Declare ship type
string type;

// Declare length of int type for points on grid
int length;

// Coordinates of grid with max length of ship (0-4)
Arr board[5];

Ship[SHIPTYPE]; 

enum direct h, v; 

struct Placeship{ 
direct dir; 

Ship shipType; 
};


};

void Board()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            array[i][j] = '-';
        }
    }
}

void VBoard()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            cout << array[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

// Make a function that allows for ship placement
Placeship(){
    int x, y, z;
    Placeship sp;

    // Bad return
    sp.shipType.board[0].X = -1;

    // User input for integers
    cin >> x >> y >> z;

    if(x!=0 && x! = 1){
        return sp;
    }

    else if (y < 0 || y >= ROWS){
        return sp;
    }
    else (y > 0 || y >= COLS){
        return sp;
    }

    // Include direction: Horizontal and Vertical

    sp.direction = (direct)x;
    sp.shipType.board[0].X = y;
    sp.shipType.board[0].Y = z;
    return sp;
}

// Create function to set or load ships
void setShip(){

// Include data for ships

ship_t[0].type = "Frigate"; ship_t[0].length = 2;
ship_t[1].type = "Sub"; ship_t[1].length = 3;
ship_t[2].type = "Destroyer"; ship_t[2].length = 3;
ship_t[3].type = "Battleship"; ship_t[3].length = 4;
ship_t[4].type = "Aircraft Carrier"; ship_t[4].length = 5;
}

int main()
{

//Call functions 
    Board();
    VBoard();
    Placeship();
    setShip();



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Rethink the `Ship` class. To me a should class should know the class of the ship (probably an `enum`), the location of the ship (an x,y pair) and the length of the ship. The ship class as defined contains none of this information.

Comment: When you don't know where to start with a problem, make the problem smaller by breaking it up and attacking the smaller problems. Keep breaking problems up until you have a good idea how to solve the problem (or at least an idea of where to look for potential solutions). One you have a list of small problems, solve them, test them so you know they are solved individually, and assemble the small solutions into bigger solutions, testing as you go.

Comment: Hi @user4581301 unfortunately my project calls for a class but I did try out the enum like you've suggested (not sure if I did it correctly though).  And thank you for the tip!  I've been so overwhelmed with my programming projects lately.

Comment: Apologies for being ambiguous. `class Ship` should know the class of the ship, Something like `enum shipclass {Frigate, Sub, Destroyer, Battleship, AircraftCarrier};` Your revision looks much better, much better thought out. Unfortunately, with the edit you're rendered the remaining answer somewhat incoherent.

Comment: General suggestions: iterate. Make sure you can compile and run your project all the time. Don’t add new features until everything works. And name your stuff appropriately. What is “Arr”? It is typically called “Point”. If you hav a class for Ship, make one for Board, then your VBoard will be Board’s Display method.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a homework? It is asking you to define a class for the `Ship` object with two (so far) properties: a type/name (can be reduced to a single character), and a length. Here is one way of doing this:

```
class Ship
{
public:
  Ship(char n) : n_(n)
  {
    switch(n_)
    {
      case 'F': len_ = 2; break;
      case 'S': len_ = 3; break;
      case 'D': len_ = 3; break;
      case 'B': len_ = 4; break;
      case 'A': len_ = 5; break;
      default: // process bad input
    }
  }
private:
  char n_;
  int len_;
}
```

However, being familiar with the game, I know that ships don't play any role in it: the board is responsible for `hit` / `miss` response, and everything else. So I don't think you need that `Ship` class at all!

Please ask another question

Comment: Without a ship class, how does one determine when the ship is sunk or destroyed?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews by looking up/down/left/right for continuation of that ship?

Comment: Hi @VladFeinstein thank you for showing me the switch case way of doing it.  Unfortunately, I have to use a class for this project :(

Comment: @assembly-bot the switch is inside the class. You may be taking the instructions further than the instructor intended. I recommend asking the instructor for clarifications.